# Can I store both a Point and a Polygon in GeoJSON format for a single feature?

Tags: geojson, geometry, mongodb

I've generated a GeoJSON file using ogr2ogr from an ESRI Shapefile for UK Protected Wrecks provided by Historic England - the standard format for the outputted GeoJSON is:

```
{
  "type":"Feature",
  "properties":{
    "ListEntry":1000043,
    "Name":"HMS\/m A1",
    "DesigDate":"1998-11-04",
    "LegacyUID":"911782",
    "SInumber":"1998\/2708\n2004\/2395",
    "AmendDate":"2004-10-05",
    "Latitude":50.74251829,
    "Longitude":-0.92132,
    "Easting":476206.35448699998,
    "Northing":94211.245704100002,
    "AREA_HA":28.238722280800001,
    "Hyperlink":"https:\/\/historicengland.org.uk\/listing\/the-list\/list-entry\/1000043"
  },
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[
      [
        [
          -0.921053211377258,
          50.73982686135377
        ],
        [
          -0.921319931341618,
          50.739821495575519
        ],
        [
          -0.921586803074952,
          50.739826860085856
        ],
        [
          -0.921852682712183,
          50.739842785133959
        ],
        [
          -0.922116371451876,
          50.739869271337817
        ],
        [
          -0.922376888692504,
          50.739906321342211
        ],
        [
          -0.922633365181112,
          50.7399535934995
        ],
        [
          -0.922884493925816,
          50.740010922885169
        ],
        [
          -0.923129584259222,
          50.740078151175176
        ],
        [
          -0.923367458509566,
          50.740155096669646
        ],
        [
          -0.923597287801228,
          50.740241260747069
        ],
        [
          -0.923818068308893,
          50.740336480412466
        ],
        [
          -0.924028957585509,
          50.740440414306129
        ],
        [
          -0.924229287896487,
          50.740552393541655
        ],
        [
          -0.924418045383537,
          50.740672256842259
        ],
        [
          -0.924594739643904,
          50.740799325270572
        ],
        [
          -0.924758346006215,
          50.740933102915804
        ],
        [
          -0.924908391860252,
          50.741073245542815
        ],
        [
          -0.925044338137426,
          50.741219091749898
        ],
        [
          -0.925165544011153,
          50.74136996660507
        ],
        [
          -0.925271655704711,
          50.741525532356611
        ],
        [
          -0.925362020321129,
          50.74168495837651
        ],
        [
          -0.925436613517539,
          50.741847568207319
        ],
        [
          -0.925494781956336,
          50.742012858550453
        ],
        [
          -0.925536695696425,
          50.742180327392205
        ],
        [
          -0.925561674431689,
          50.74234897656109
        ],
        [
          -0.925570218797828,
          50.742518288189977
        ],
        [
          -0.925561834889821,
          50.742687603046342
        ],
        [
          -0.92553669807626,
          50.742856248271508
        ],
        [
          -0.925494958265783,
          50.743023548966583
        ],
        [
          -0.925436614923385,
          50.743188839631216
        ],
        [
          -0.925362185343822,
          50.74335161870443
        ],
        [
          -0.925271820479418,
          50.743511043109173
        ],
        [
          -0.925165709857077,
          50.74366644278242
        ],
        [
          -0.925044507360034,
          50.743817481077109
        ],
        [
          -0.924908556401517,
          50.743963330163851
        ],
        [
          -0.924758513608514,
          50.744103473554809
        ],
        [
          -0.924594904369409,
          50.744237246965092
        ],
        [
          -0.924418382556721,
          50.744364318233174
        ],
        [
          -0.924229624442886,
          50.744484182739008
        ],
        [
          -0.924029291798829,
          50.744596165762381
        ],
        [
          -0.923818230418854,
          50.744700098786211
        ],
        [
          -0.923597453373799,
          50.744795318429468
        ],
        [
          -0.923367623351867,
          50.744881484525848
        ],
        [
          -0.923129744951845,
          50.744958429135977
        ],
        [
          -0.922884658916512,
          50.74502565187327
        ],
        [
          -0.922633373217608,
          50.745083148513451
        ],
        [
          -0.922377054461851,
          50.745130426189689
        ],
        [
          -0.922116371725032,
          50.745167303099166
        ],
        [
          -0.921852675624734,
          50.745193792596282
        ],
        [
          -0.921586809412671,
          50.745209720799288
        ],
        [
          -0.921319929911502,
          50.745215084902021
        ],
        [
          -0.921053045996393,
          50.745209720665699
        ],
        [
          -0.920787339075089,
          50.745193789203327
        ],
        [
          -0.920523483667514,
          50.74516730485864
        ],
        [
          -0.920262970215599,
          50.745130426227497
        ],
        [
          -0.920006486412283,
          50.745083148907732
        ],
        [
          -0.919755356425044,
          50.745025649760215
        ],
        [
          -0.919510273383637,
          50.744958426254769
        ],
        [
          -0.919272399531752,
          50.744881483802203
        ],
        [
          -0.919042565497366,
          50.744795317561852
        ],
        [
          -0.918821616421575,
          50.744700099086522
        ],
        [
          -0.918610729602765,
          50.744596162188252
        ],
        [
          -0.918410395610808,
          50.744484178747165
        ],
        [
          -0.918221636749465,
          50.744364317474066
        ],
        [
          -0.918045113561331,
          50.744237252728396
        ],
        [
          -0.917881329203046,
          50.744103475752183
        ],
        [
          -0.917731294775485,
          50.743963330518682
        ],
        [
          -0.9175955121779,
          50.74381748361975
        ],
        [
          -0.917474309783834,
          50.743666442657378
        ],
        [
          -0.917368195573496,
          50.743511038844467
        ],
        [
          -0.91727783748625,
          50.743351619255684
        ],
        [
          -0.917203237273505,
          50.743188839530276
        ],
        [
          -0.917145066817832,
          50.743023550374907
        ],
        [
          -0.917103327344731,
          50.742856244639682
        ],
        [
          -0.91707818436289,
          50.74268760464593
        ],
        [
          -0.917069801141472,
          50.742518286607833
        ],
        [
          -0.917078177369341,
          50.742348972192566
        ],
        [
          -0.917103327216529,
          50.742180329705135
        ],
        [
          -0.917145071689608,
          50.742012861079012
        ],
        [
          -0.917203405919222,
          50.741847568966222
        ],
        [
          -0.917277837611697,
          50.741684959572424
        ],
        [
          -0.917368364924271,
          50.741525536455896
        ],
        [
          -0.917474473418709,
          50.741369968377484
        ],
        [
          -0.917595680142749,
          50.741219096151177
        ],
        [
          -0.917731637253649,
          50.741073249242191
        ],
        [
          -0.917881672908469,
          50.740933103032319
        ],
        [
          -0.91804528976143,
          50.740799326426547
        ],
        [
          -0.918221806744875,
          50.740672259280146
        ],
        [
          -0.91841073060137,
          50.740552395170582
        ],
        [
          -0.918610893458338,
          50.740440413868789
        ],
        [
          -0.918821955716995,
          50.740336477639616
        ],
        [
          -0.919042731243519,
          50.740241261593553
        ],
        [
          -0.919272563496759,
          50.740155092331399
        ],
        [
          -0.919510443619816,
          50.740078149305738
        ],
        [
          -0.91975552696369,
          50.740010929149008
        ],
        [
          -0.920006654851573,
          50.739953595550006
        ],
        [
          -0.920263133331028,
          50.739906318307099
        ],
        [
          -0.920523643334552,
          50.739869273128996
        ],
        [
          -0.920787338647848,
          50.739842781300474
        ],
        [
          -0.921053211377258,
          50.73982686135377
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
```

I want to store the data in MongoDB to work with MongoDB GeoSpatial queries - I'm interested in performing queries against the Latitude and Longitude in the "properties" key of the GeoJSON entry so I'm considering adding a Point to the GeoJSON data.

As it's my data store I can sort of fudge the data to make it work but I'm curious -  can a Point and a Polygon be added to a single GeoJSON feature entry? My reading of RFC 7946 (Section 3.1) seems to indicate that you can't add both a Point and a Polygon to a single entry and you'd effectively need to duplicate the entry if you wanted both items stored as geometries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GeometryCollection` as stated in the specs e.g https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.8

You can find in the same spec in the appendix an example e.g https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#appendix-A.7 or a more complete sample at https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8873

Comment: Perfect - thank you!